# Jittery Search Bar Cancel / End Editing Animation

Tags: ios, swift, ios-animations

I have a SearchBar and am trying to make it behave like one you'd see in the iPhone settings. When it's tapped the animation smoothly transitions the magnifying glass from the middle of the search bar to the left side of the search bar & smoothly brings in the cancel button. However, when I press cancel the animation freezes up then jumps back to normal, with the search icon in the middle of the bar and the cancel button hidden (see GIF preview). Is something in my code making this happen? This is the search bar code:

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your necessary code in

```
public func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool
```

Not sure why you have to do it in `shouldEnd` for hiding the button but `didBegin` for showing

```
public func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
}

public func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    return true
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Matthew. I was also wondering, could you share your code for searchBarCancelButtonClicked? That's the one I'm having trouble with now. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you'd like to "close" the search bar. Resigning the field should work. Edited my post.